# Why do I keep getting a "Bad Request: 400" error on my bot with discord.net?

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I'm making a discord bot using c# with a library called [DSharpPlus](https://github.com/DSharpPlus) (if that helps a bit), and I'm trying to make a purge command but I keep getting a

> Bad Request: 400

error and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried looking for it online and couldn't find any, plus I'm also kinda new to C# and have done so much on it already that I can't go back. Here's my code:

```
    [Command("purge")]
    [Description("Deleted A Certain Number Of Messages. (Max = 1000)")]
    [RequireBotPermissions(Permissions.Administrator)]
    [RequireUserPermissions(Permissions.Administrator)]
    public async Task Purge(CommandContext ctx, [Description("Number Of Messages To Be Deleted.")]int num)
    {
        int limit = 1000;
        
        if (num > limit)
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Too Many Arguments. Limit: 1000").ConfigureAwait(false);

        await ctx.Message.DeleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var messages = await ctx.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(num).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await ctx.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(messages).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
        {
            Title = $"{num} Messages Deleted!",
            Color = DiscordColor.Aquamarine
        };
        var deletedMessage = await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Thread.Sleep(4300);
        await ctx.Channel.DeleteMessageAsync(deletedMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

If it looks bad, again I'm new to C# so I don't know much. Please help because I've tried so many times that I just need to find help now. Thanks!

**EDIT**: basically the command dose indeed work but then it gives me a error for `Bad Request: 400` and I don't really know why.

Here's what I keep getting if that also helps:

> Nitro7256 tried executing 'purge' but it errorred: DSharpPlus.Exceptions.BadRequestException: Bad request: 400

Comment: A 400 Bad Request is a HTTP response code, not a .NET exception. It's not clear from your code if/where you are making a HTTP request so please clarify that in your question. Additionally, the response code indicates a malformed request, ensure you are following whatever API docs exist for the API you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Late to the party)

If you read the discord documentation, it tells you the reasons for it sending back 400 error.

1. The message limit on bulk delete is 100, not 1,000. This is also the case with getting messages
2. If the messages are too old, it will also return a 400 error.

From the bulk delete docs itself:

```
This endpoint will not delete messages older than 2 weeks, and will fail with a 400 BAD REQUEST if any message provided is older than that or if any duplicate message IDs are provided.
```

Get Messages docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages

Bulk Delete docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#bulk-delete-messages

Obviously you dont need to manually send the request. This is just showing you the reasons for 400 Error Response.

Side Note:

Use `await Task.Delay(4300)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(4300)`. `Thread.Sleep()` blocks the main thread.

Comment: so then is there another way I can do my purge command?

Comment: Guess you could use the single message delete. That allows you to delete messages older than 2 weeks. Could try checking each message for the date. 

Tbh you shouldnt be getting a 400 error unless lib is broken or you are indeed deleting messages older than 2 weeks

Comment: yh i think i am deleting messages older than 2 weeks, but ill try making it check the dates of the messages before deleting them